# How to access facebook comments from fb-widget on a page of my app into another one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, comments, koala

In my ruby on rails app, I'm working on localhost but also tried with ngrok. Neither way works. I am using the facebook graph api with the koala gem as well as the facebook widget for comments in my app.

On one view page (1), a user can comment on a certain post. I want to display the comments from that view page on a different view page (2) . Problem: they do not display and I get an empty data-has although there are comments on viewpage 1.

Here is the comments widget on viewpage 1 (managed by offers-controller):

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://13c67f21.ngrok.com/offers/<%=current_user.offers.last.id%>/details" data-width="800" data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

And this is my comments-controller:

```
  def index
   @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new
   @offer = current_user.offers.last.id
   urls_offer = ['http://13c67f21.ngrok.com/offers/<%=@offer%>/details']
   @offer_comments = @graph.get_comments_for_urls(urls_offer)
  end
```

Viewpage 2 (mnanaged by comments-controller):

```
  <%= @offer_comments %>
```

And what the browser gives me is this:

```
{"http://13c67f21.ngrok.com/offers/<%=@offer%>/details"=>{"comments"=>{"data"=>[]}}}
```

Any help appreciated!!!

Comment: You can't use ERB syntax in your controller. Change `'http://13c67f21.ngrok.com/offers/<%=@offer%>/details'` to `"http://13c67f21.ngrok.com/offers/#{@offer}/details"`

Comment: Thanks @mechanicalfish. Besides the fact that that is of course totally true (what a brainfart haha), it still gives me the empty value to the data-key in the comments hash. Do you think there needs to go an access token somewhere? What else could be the problem?

Comment: It still does weird things to the url around @offer where the :id goes:    {"http://13c67f21.ngrok.com/offers/\#{@offer}/details"=>{"comments"=>{"data"=>[]}}}

Comment: You have to use double quotes. Can't help you with the API as I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: mmmh played around a bit and changed some things but double quotes might have done the trick :-) at least i am getting the comments now. saved me from pulling them out with jquery - yay!